# JavaScript ES6 prototype function

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype

I would like to make the `getArea()` function a prototype, and am not sure if this ES6 (?) format is automatically doing this for me, or do I still need to declare a prototype in a separate `Object.prototype.method = function() {}`
construct?

```
class Polygon {
    constructor(height, width) {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
    getArea() {
        return this.height * this.width;
    }
}
```

Comment: [See the confirmation by yourself](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAKD2ICeBzeA7aBvAUNf0wGEALgE4CuwJ8ZAFABYCmAligyQDTQDuLAJiQYBKbHgIShLCADpmbDtAC80eexIBucRPxTZfQQ2W8BQrRIC-26CiYkAgmSZg6o3DoJOSFMpj1zWdWgAKmh_AzNrKwsgA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015-loose&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0)

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just check for yourself? `console.log(Polygon.prototype.getarea)`

Answer (score 6):

It is.

The ES6 class format basically translates to something like this:

```
function Polygon(height, width) {
  this.height = height;
  this.width = width;
}

Polygon.prototype.getArea = function() {
    return this.height * this.width;
};
```

Comment: Further confirmation - I just compiled the code from the question using TypeScript and Babel and this is pretty much exactly the code that gets output.

Comment: An important distinction would be that the method would be non-enumerable.

Comment: I'm not sure how ES6 or ES5 syntax would really differ in that regard.

Comment: The ES5 syntax you're using makes it so `getArea` will show up when enumerating the properties of an instance. `for (var x in new Polygon()) { console.log(x) }`. But in ES6, because it's non-enumerable, `getArea` won't show up in the loop. To get that behavior in ES5 browsers, you'd use `Object.defineProperty` to add the method to the prototype.

Comment: Ah, good point. I don't think I realized that myself. Just tested it myself and that is definitely the case.